# Is there a way to test non-exported functions from component using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, test-coverage

I want to test a non-exported function from a component in unit test case, in order to check if that function is being called or not.
I am not able to test non-exported methods and it is resulting into very low coverage of unit test case.

Also if someone can guide here for improving statement coverage?

please help!

Comment: Is the function internal to a react component? or just some function that isn't exported? Can you share here actual code, test code, what you've attempted?

Comment: If you want to test the non-exported function then you will have to export it(No other way).

Comment: @DrewReese yes the function is internal to a component

Comment: @MilindAgrawal I Cant, as its a legacy code and i cant export each and every function of the component

Comment: If you can't factor the function out to be tested in isolation then you'll have to examine what external values (props) trace through the component and trigger a call to the function you want coverage on. React-testing-library works by unit testing components at the API level (what props can be passed to them) or by how users can interact with them (the UI). If the component is a class-based component then you may be able to do some jest spying. If you want/need any more help than this I afraid you may need to share some actual component and unit test code.

Comment: if you export every function for the testing, then you violate the incapsulation principle